# Ionic Ion-checkbox change color in Typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, checkbox, colors, ion-checkbox

I want to change the color of the ion-checkbox in the typescript

```
  <ion-item >
    <ion-label id="check1">No</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox color="blue"  id="box1" [(ngModel)]="todo.check1"  name="check1"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
```

I try this:

```
document.getElementById("box1").color = "dark";
```

but it doesn't work

I also try to change the class: doesn't work

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
document.getElementById("box1").setAttribute("color", "dark")
```

or

```
document.getElementById("box1").style.color = "dark"
```

The first will change the color attribute of the element, while the second changes the css style for color of the element.

For typescript to be happy, you may also have to cast the result of your `getElementById` call. I.E.

```
(document.getElementById("box1") as HTMLElement).style.color ...
```

Comment: Hmm. Well after messing with it a little, it looks like the checkbox itself is contained in the `<ion-checkbox>` element as a child node. But it has the class `checkbox-icon`, so we can get it by doing `const icon = document.getElementById("box1").querySelector(".checkbox-icon")`. Then, since it's the background color you need to change, do: `icon.style.backgroundColor = "... some color"`. Keep in mind that `dark` is not a valid color. You'll have to use either a hex string or one of the predefined html colors.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work, if i look to the code the color has update, but not the result

Comment: I have this erro : cannot read property 'style of null, then I do this :     document.getElementById("box1").style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
the background of the checkbox change but the round stay blue

Comment: If the border remains blue you just have to change that color as well as the background color. So it would then be: `document.getElementById("box1").style.borderColor = "#000000"` in addition to the background color change.

Comment: No the problem is not the border: inside the round of the checkbox it is blue and I have a square outside black

Comment: I find the solution I do this :     document.getElementById("box1").getElementsByClassName( 'checkbox-icon checkbox-checked' )[0].style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
 thank for your help